# Android not able to completely remove CardView's margins/paddings and rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am using a Pre-LolliPop Android phone for development, and now I have a RecyclerView which involves a layout included CardView with images and texts. I try to  trim all the margins the widget brings to it in default like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/adapter_itemlist_category_cardview_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/adapter_itemlist_category_cardview_height"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_itemlist_category_cardview"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp" 
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >

        <!-- some inner content-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting `android:background="@android:color/black"` in the `LinearLayout` is for visually viewing if there are still any spaces/margin exist.

However, even when I have set both card_view:cardElevation="0dp" and card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp", there are still like a few dp light grey margin between the CardViews items within the RecyclerView, apparently due to the round corners (and I don't want it to be rounded corner anyway):
[image: Corners, and there are little light grey spacings between the items]

And then I try to set the round corner radius to 0 dp, but the I found that if setting `card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"`, it will turn of to the following errors during executions:

```
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.graphics.RadialGradient.<init>(RadialGradient.java:34)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.buildShadowCorners(RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.java:285)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.buildComponents(RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.java:307)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.draw(RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.java:209)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13744)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12710)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13762)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12710)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:3558)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13762)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3037)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12710)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13762)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12710)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12708)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13762)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1806)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12710)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13483)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3169)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3039)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12708)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3151)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12646)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12754)
07-30 00:49:49.219: E/AndroidRuntime(16237):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGrou
```

Whichs turns out this property cannot be set to zero-value.

Therefore, is there a way to completely remove the rounded corners for CardView in pre-Lollipop devices? And if even the margins/paddings made by that? If not, how to remove them completely?

Comment: Why are you even using CardView then? The entire point of CardView is the elevation shadow and the rounded corners.

Comment: You are right, after I switched the CardView to normal LinearLayout then all these problems are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to non-cardview and it worked for me.